# Haskell monad: IO [Double] to [IO Double]

Tags: haskell, random, io, monads

Consider the following code that is supposed to print out random numbers:

```
import System.Random.Mersenne

main =
 do g <- (newMTGen Nothing)
    xs <- (randoms g) :: IO [Double]
    mapM_ print xs
```

When run, I get a segmentation fault error. That is unsurprising, since the function 'randoms' produces an infinite list. Suppose I wanted to print out only the first ten values of xs. How could I do that? xs has type IO [Double], and I think I want a variable of type [IO Double]. What operators exist to convert between the two.

Comment: Incidentally, IO [Double] -> [IO Double] is essentially the reverse type signature of 'sequence'.

Comment: Sounds like a miscompilation of some kind or a hardware issue, then... you might want to run a [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) check.

Comment: You could do a `IO [Double] -> IO [IO Double]` ... unless you `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: That stray `-}` is quite unusual.

Comment: Daniel, does the code work properly for you? and the } is a typo

Answer (score 11):

If you get a segmentation fault error, and you didn't use the FFI or any functions with `unsafe` in their name, that's *not* unsurprising, in any situation! It means there's a bug with either GHC, or a library you're using is doing something unsafe.

Printing out an infinite list of `Double`s with `mapM_ print` is perfectly fine; the list will be processed incrementally and the program should run with constant memory usage. I suspect there is a bug in the `System.Random.Mersenne` module you're using, or a bug the C library it's based on, or a problem with your computer (such as faulty RAM).<sup>1</sup> Note that [`newMTGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mersenne-random/latest/doc/html/System-Random-Mersenne.html#v:newMTGen) comes with this warning:

> Due to the current SFMT library being vastly impure, currently only a single generator is allowed per-program. Attempts to reinitialise it will fail.

You might be better off using the provided [global `MTGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mersenne-random/latest/doc/html/System-Random-Mersenne.html#v:getStdRandom) instead.

That said, you can't convert `IO [Double]` into `[IO Double]` in that way; there's no way to know how long the resulting list would be without executing the `IO` action, which is impossible, since you have a pure result (albeit one that happens to contain `IO` actions). For infinite lists, you could write:

```
desequence :: IO [a] -> [IO a]
desequence = desequence' 0
  where
    desequence n m = fmap (!! n) m : desequence (n+1) m
```

But every time you execute an action in this list, the `IO [a]` action would be executed again; it'd just discard the rest of the list.

The reason `randoms` can work and return an infinite list of random numbers is because it uses lazy IO with `unsafeInterleaveIO`. (Note that, despite the "unsafe" in the name, this one *can't* cause segfaults, so something else is afoot.)

<sup>1</sup> Other, less likely possibilities include a miscompilation of the C library, or a bug in GHC.

Comment: Just for the record, I think it's possible something is wrong with the questioner's computer, not with the library; the supplied code doesn't segfault for me.

Comment: +1 for "you can't convert `IO [Double]` into `[IO Double]`... there's no way to know how long the resulting list would be without executing the IO action"

Comment: So there is no way to access just the first ten list elements?

Comment: @Gautam: Sure there is, just use `take` on the resulting list: `mapM_ print (take 10 xs)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, you are correct, when I recompiled the mersenne-random package without using the -f use sse_2 flag, it worked without a segfault. That is slightly worrying, since the -f use sse_2 flag is supposed to be set so that the module can take advantage of SIMD optimization.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, it could also be a bug in the SSE2-specific C code that the library contains.

Comment: this doesn't answer a direct question (about 10 values), and fails to correct the OP's basic misunderstanding with the type, instead discussing a misformulated question as if it had merit here. (-1)

Answer (score 11):

> Suppose I wanted to print out only the first ten values of xs. How could I do that?

Just use `take`:

```
main =
 do g <- (newMTGen Nothing)
    xs <- (randoms g) :: IO [Double]
    mapM_ print $ take 10 xs
```

You wrote

> xs has type IO [Double]

But actually, `randoms g` has type `IO [Double]`, but thanks to the `do` notation, `xs` has type `[Double]`, you can just apply `take 10` to it.

You could also skip the binding using `liftM`:

```
main =
  do g <- newMTGen Nothing
     ys <- liftM (take 10) $ randoms g :: IO [Double]
     mapM_ print ys
```